# Can't load scripts because of node.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js

I can't use `<script src="node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>` 
in my index.html file because of:

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
>   http://localhost:8080/node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js

This happens because of my else statement in server file code:

```
var http = require('http')
var url = require('url')
var fs = require('fs')

var server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
let parsedUrl = url.parse(req.url, true)

if (parsedUrl.pathname === '/') {
    console.log('home page')
    fs.readFile('./index.html', (err, data) => {
        res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/html' })
        res.end(data)
    })
} else if (parsedUrl.pathname === '/readJson') {
    console.log('read json')
    fs.readFile('./data.json', (err, data) => {
        res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' })
        res.end(data)
    })
} else {
    console.log('We can\'nt load any resources because of this statement')
    res.writeHead(404)
    res.end()
}
})
server.listen(8080)
```

I've read about how to fix this problem when using express module. Is there any way to solve the problem without using that module?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way would be to simply load jQuery from a CDN instead of serving it from your own server. This is a widely accepted best practice.

Example:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

You can find various options for loading jQuery from a CDN here: https://code.jquery.com

If you create an HTTP server like in your code example and want it to serve jQuery, then you'd have to read the `jquery.min.js` using `fs.readFile` and serve its contents, just like you're doing with your `data.json` file.

Comment: Thank you. That helps. Anyway I still want to find a solution which stands only on currently loaded modules and files. Just curious if that's possible

Comment: it's possible, but I wouldn't recommend it. Added some clarification to my answer

Comment: I had that idea from the beginning ( to read the jquery.min.js using fs.readFile ) . But I think it's a kind of monstrous solution. Don't you think so? Maybe it's better to make the file visible for front-end part?

Comment: It is monstrous, but I think there is a misconception on your part. What do you mean by “make the file visible”? You are setting up an HTTP server that handles requests and serves data. The only way to serve data from your local file system to the client is through this server.

Comment: I mean using a folder with public available files. How could that be implemented?

Comment: You'd have to basically write all the code yourself: scan the folder for files, load each file, math incoming requests for those files, send the file contents for those. You'd reinvent the wheel. You should really look into using Express, it has a middleware for serving static files that makes this really easy.

Comment: I'm really reluctant to add a code example showing how to do this manually, because I would never recommend to anyone doing it this way

Comment: Thank you much for your help. I think now I can start to learn and use express. And good point is that you helped me to understand how that stuff could be implemented manually. Thank you for your time and consideration!

Comment: Glad to help. Please accept my answer if it helped you.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend the use a CDN instead. If you install the jQuery module you can use it for your back-end JavasSript. However you want to use it on the front-end. You are using NodeJS as web server to serve a HTML page. The http module doesn't know anything about other files because it only read the `index.html`.

So you might wanna search for a solution to read/serve a complete folder. Withing this folder, lets call it `public`, you can store you HTML, CSS and JS files that are public available. Since the HTTP module knows about the entire folder all files can be used on the front-end. This is also a good solution to separate your back-end en front-end JavaScript.

Comment: Thank you for response. I think that's a solution I'm looking for. Just one more question if you don't mind: How can I make node.js read/serve a complete folder?

Comment: instead of `fs.readFile('./index.html', ....)` you can use `fs.readFile(path_to_public_folder + '/' + parsedUrl.pathname, ....)`. You might want to make sure that the  parsedUrl.pathname` is alway lowercase. Think the `url.parse` does that already for you.

You can also use express. See https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html.